# VBA parse dom to find one particular href value

Tags: excel, vba, dom, xpath

Using Excel VBA, since all the french versions of the URL are in a .xls file, I have to find about 400 URLs from the english version of the same site.

Knowing the dom structure of the site, I know that I can:

- Open the webpage (MSXML2.XMLHTTP)
- Search for one particular link in the header of the webpage.  The link that gives the ability for a user to switch language.  Under that link (href) I'll be able to find the english link and that is all I need.
- After that, I'll manage to copy that result in the corresponding cell in my worksheet.

The structure is like so.  The "English" link changes but always under this structure:

```
<ul class="global-links">
<li><a title="Nous joindre" href="/fr/coordonnees.html">Nous Joindre</a></li>
<li>|</li>
<li><a title="Carrières" href="/fr/carrieres.html">Carrières</a></li>
<li>|</li>        
<li><a title="English" href="/en/personal.html">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

The href I want is the one on the link which has the title "English" on it.

Were I'm stuck is that I know that there is two ways to find the relevant text

- getElement... (directly parsing the DOM)
- inStr (string manipulation)

I managed to test both of them but:

- Manipulating the DOM: I would have thought that the following would have work but not at all and it gives me a 438 error.  And also, I don't understand if there would be a possibility to target a href that as "English" for its title (since there is no special class or id on it)

  .getElementsByClassName("global-links").innertext
- So I changed for the instr method (manipulating the positions to do a MID afterward... I search for

  InStr(1, htm.body.innerHTML, "title=""English"" href=")

I can't construct the string I want to search for in the good manner because of the double quotes.  I tried doubling the double quotes.  I tried also the chr(34) method like so

```
"title=" & Chr(34) & "English" & Chr(34) & " href=" & Chr(34)
```

But I can't make it work either, it doesn't find my string.

So I need help to find the href value of the link which has "English" for its title, either via DOM search or string search.

Finally, since it's for a loop, is there a best practice for the creation object/memory use?  How needs to be handled the closing of the object/connexion create for one instance in order to free memory or not overloading it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

An example can be found here: https://www.bnc.ca/fr/particuliers.html

### EDIT to give starting code

```
Sub testAlias()
'title="English" href="https://www.nbc.ca
Dim htm As HTMLDocument, table As Object
Set htm = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.bnc.ca/fr/particuliers.html", False
    .send
    htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    'Code to continue here...
    'Assuming I need to target the <a> with "English" for title and retrieve its href value
End With
End Sub
```

### EDIT - Code with loop not working

Based on David's answer, I created a loop from values in one cell on my worksheet.  I need to append the value and my domain name.

The domain is https://www.bnc.ca and here are values I test that doesn't work:

- /en/particuliers/cartes-de-credit/cartes-de-credit-mastercard/avec-plan-recompenses/allure.html
- /en/particuliers/cartes-de-credit/cartes-de-credit-mastercard/avec-plan-recompenses/or-ovation.html

I have an error on the foreach line stating the #91 error (undefined variable/object or with bloc...)

```
For Each e In elements(0).ChildNodes
```

Can somebody help me on how to resolve that part please?

```
Sub testAlias()


For rid = 2 To 3
'Dim sh As Worksheet
'Set sh = ActiveSheet



Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet

Dim url As String
url = "https://www.bnc.ca" & sh.Cells(rid, 1)

'title="English" href="https://www.nbc.ca
Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim DOM As Object 'MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim elements As Object
Dim ele As Object
Dim respText As String

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set DOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'for some reason, I can't use CreateObject to do this

'## Create the HTTPRequest
With http
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send ""
    '## Load the XML to DOM
    respText = .responseText

End With

'## Put in HTML Document
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = respText
Debug.Print respText

'## Parse DOM
Set elements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("global-links")

'If elements Is Not Nothing Then


    '## Assume there is only one class name "global-links"
    For Each e In elements(0).ChildNodes
        If e.innerText = "English" Then
            '## Display the url:
            sh.Cells(rid, 2).Formula = ""
            sh.Cells(rid, 2).Formula = e.ChildNodes(0).href
        End If
    Next
    DoEvents
'End If



Next rid
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I have no problem using `Instr` after copy/pasting both your structure, and your arguments (except for putting the structure into a string constant..  Instr returns `212`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can brute-force it with something like this, otherwise I would probably try to use XPath or a more robust application of the DOM parsing (would need to see more of the XML structure to assist with that):

```vb
Sub foo()
Dim xmlString As String

xmlString = "<ul class=""global-links"">" & _
"<li><a title=""Nous joindre"" href=""/fr/coordonnees.html"">Nous Joindre</a></li>" & _
"<li>|</li>" & _
"<li><a title=""Carrières"" href=""/fr/carrieres.html"">Carrières</a></li>" & _
"<li>|</li>" & _
"<li><a title=""English"" href=""/en/personal.html"">English</a></li>" & _
"</ul>"

Dim DOM As Object
Set DOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDOCUMENT")
DOM.LoadXML xmlString


Dim elements
Dim e
Set elements = DOM.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("a")

For Each e In elements
    On Error Resume Next
    If e.ParentNode.ParentNode.XML Like "<ul class=""global-links"">*" Then
        If e.XML Like "<a title=""English"" href=*" Then
            MsgBox e.XML
        End If
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

**Update**

I was unable to use DOM (kept getting a parse error when trying to load the `HTML.responseText` so I went back to using the HTMLDocument object instead:

```vb
Sub testAlias()
'title="English" href="https://www.nbc.ca
Dim HTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim DOM As Object 'MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim elements As Object
Dim ele As Object
Dim respText As String

Set HTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set DOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'for some reason, I can't use CreateObject to do this

'## Create the HTTPRequest
With HTTP
    .Open "GET", "https://www.bnc.ca/fr/particuliers.html", False
    .send ""
    '## Load the XML to DOM
    respText = .responseText

End With

'## Put in HTML Document
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = respText

'## I tried loading in to DOM but it would not work:
'DOM.LoadXML respText
'If DOM.parseError Then
'    MsgBox DOM.parseError.reason
'    Stop
'End If

'## Parse DOM
Set elements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("global-links")

'## Assume there is only one class name "global-links"
For Each e In elements(0).ChildNodes
    If e.innerText = "English" Then
        '## Display the url:
        MsgBox e.ChildNodes(0).href
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David.  Since it's a one shot deal.  I'll give your solution a try and come back to you with the result.  But it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Hello,  I have some trouble getting the responsetext from the dom creatobjectc to load on dom.loadxml in order to do what you did but as stated, could I give you the path of a page to give me more assistance in xpath?  https://www.bnc.ca/fr/particuliers.html (it's the "English" link on top).

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I'll also try to close the gap!

Comment: Can you update your Q to show the code you're using to get the XMLHTTP response text?

Comment: Done.  Do you need more info?  I have more code to show but since nothing works, I'm not sure it would be relevant to show you non-working code.

Comment: OK, I think that's enough, i'll play with it for a minute.

Comment: I'm getting a parse error when I try to load the XML using DOM. That suggests a problem with the `.responseText`, and I don't think that is something I'm able to help with at the moment. I'll update my answer with the details, in case it may be of use to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72518/discussion-between-eric-thibeault-and-david-zemens).

Comment: See updated answer. I was able to do it with HTMLDocument object instead of DOMDocument.

Comment: Thanks a lot David.  For some unknown reason 
`HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = respText` gives me a 91 error about the with bloc.  I also try `HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText` instead inside the with and gives me the same error.

Comment: Typo in my code... the line that says `Set HTML = ...` **should** say `Set HTMLDoc = ...`

Comment: YEAH.  That's all that was problematic.  Now I can see the english URL.  I'll now have to loop through my sheet to get all the related links.  But the part I was wondering is now solved.  Thanks to you in really good part!

Comment: I'll update the Q with my finished and working code after all my tests.